# Android file canRead() is always false on SD card

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard

I am trying to read a file from the SD card, but finding that I don't have read permissions.
I first get the public storage directory and list the files like so:

```
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

Then I select one of the files and test to see if it is readable:

```
    Log.d(TAG, files[0].canRead());
```

This always displays false, and I'm not sure why. I am able to write to the directory (in fact it's the file that I've written that I want to read), and I've tried variations of

```
    files[0].setReadable(true);
```

and

```
    dir.setReadable(true);
```

with no luck. I also have

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

included in my Manifest file and made sure my device wasn't connected to anything (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214861/cant-read-write-to-sdcard-in-android)), but that wasn't it.

I am able to pull the file from the device and read it in a text editor. Any ideas as to what this could be?

Stats: Using API 12 on Samsung Galaxy tablet.

Comment: But what happens if you just go ahead and open & read it anyway?

Comment: If you are using an actual phone to test try downloading Astro. The app is an actual file manager in android. So you can search if it is in there.

Comment: I get an IOException if I try to read it. If I open up the file manager I can see the file, and I can pull it onto the computer from DDMS in Eclipse.

Comment: Did you figure out the cause and solution for this?

Comment: It's been a few years now but I don't believe I was ever able to resolve it.